Splitting PDF Files into Smaller Chunks Based on Size Using qpdf
How to split large PDFs into 200MB files? qpdf and other Linux tools can only set the number of pages each file has, not file size.

Using cpdf (disclaimer, which I wrote), you can run:
cpdf -split-max 200Mb in.pdf -o out%%%.pdf
This will never create a file larger than 200Mb, and fail if even a file with a single page would be greater than 200Mb.

This solution demonstrates how to split PDF files into smaller chunks based on a specified size using the qpdf command-line tool. The script is designed to iterate through all PDF files in a directory and split each file into parts approximately 200 MB in size.
Ubuntu
# Set the target size for each split part in bytes
target_size=$((200 * 1024 * 1024))  # 200 MB (change as needed)
# Iterate through all PDF files in the current directory
for file in *.pdf; do
    pages=$(qpdf --show-npages "$file")
    size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
    page_size=$((size / pages))
    pages_per_file=$((target_size / page_size))
    qpdf --split-pages="$pages_per_file" "$file" "/OUTPUT_PATH/$file" # OUTPUT_PATH (change as needed)
    echo "$file split into parts with approximately $pages_per_file pages each."
done

Powershell
# Set the path to qpdf.exe
$qpdfPath = "C:\Program Files\qpdf 11.9.0\bin\qpdf.exe"

# Set the maximum part size (in bytes)
$part_size = 200MB


# Loop through PDF files in the current directory
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the number of pages in the PDF
    $pages = & $qpdfPath --show-npages $_.FullName

    # Get the file size in bytes
    $size = (Get-Item $_.FullName).Length

    # Calculate the average page size
    $page_size = $size / $pages

    # Calculate the number of pages per part
    $pages_per_file = $part_size / $page_size

    # Split the PDF into parts
    & $qpdfPath --split-pages=$pages_per_file $_.FullName "/OUTPUT_PATH/$($_.Name)"# OUTPUT_PATH (change as needed)

    # Output the file name and pages per part
    Write-Output "$($_.Name) page size: $pages_per_file"
}

